# Update a row if a condition is met, otherwise do not update the column

Tags: mysql

I only want to update a row if a condition is met, if its not met keep the value originally in the column

If `finish_date` is null then `start_date` should not update, keeping the original value.

If `finish_value` is not null, update `start_date`

When I run the following query it updates `start_date` to the value passed in no matter what. What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO barcode_queue (barcode, start_date) VALUES ('X17291211902P02V0010', '2019-06-01 00:00:00') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        start_date = (CASE WHEN finish_date <> NULL THEN VALUES(start_date) ELSE start_date END), 
        finish_date = null;
```

Comment: Never compare to NULL with = or <>. Use IS  NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help forpas. Here is the solution

```
INSERT INTO barcode_queue (barcode, start_date) VALUES ('X17291211902P02V0010', '2019-06-01 00:00:00') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                start_date = (CASE WHEN finish_date IS NULL THEN start_date ELSE VALUES(start_date) END), 
                finish_date = null;
```